# Mkdirs failed to create hadoop.tmp.dir

Tags: hadoop, tmp, mkdirs

I have upgraded from Apache Hadoop 0.20.2 to the newest stable release; 0.20.203. While doing that, I've also updated all configuration files properly. However, I am getting the following error while trying to run a job via a JAR file:

```
$ hadoop jar myjar.jar
$ Mkdirs failed to create /mnt/mydisk/hadoop/tmp
```

where `/mnt/mydisk/hadoop/tmp` is the location of `hadoop.tmp.dir` as stated in the core-site.xml:

```
..
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/mnt/mydisk/hadoop/tmp</value>
</property>
..
```

I've already checked that the directory exists, and that the permissions for the user `hadoop` are set correctly. I've also tried out to delete the directory, so that Hadoop itself can create it. But that didn't help.

Executing an Hadoop job with hadoop version 0.20.2 worked out of the box. However, something is broken after the update. Can someone help me to track down the problem?

Comment: Is it possible to add the logs. That might help find out the issue. And check this, may be the CLASSPATH was not set properly - https://twiki.grid.iu.edu/bin/view/Storage/HadoopDebug#Mkdirs_failed_to_create

Comment: Sorry, but where can I find the log files?